# How to fix ValueError in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried some stuff with TensorFlow and got this error :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer gru is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 3)
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide more details - at least, which library do you use? Maybe some code snippet to reproduce an error?

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce your issue with sample code. `tf.keras.layers.GRU` expects input A 3D tensor, with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`

**Reproduced code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 8])
gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(4)
output = gru(inputs)
print(output.shape)
```

**Output**

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer gru_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (32, 8)
```

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 10, 8])
gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(4)
output = gru(inputs)
print(output.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(32, 4)
```